# Migration from MySQL to DB2 with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, db2

I want to change the database of my ruby on rails application from MySQL to DB2.
and I have the next problem:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in WelcomeController#index
>
> RuntimeError: Failed to execute statement due to: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0401N The data types of the operands for the operation "=" are not compatible or comparable. SQLSTATE=42818 SQLCODE=-401: SELECT customer_accounts.* FROM customer_accounts WHERE (status=true) AND (etl_exec=true) AND (customerAccountServer in (select tsmserver from users_accounts where user_id=90)) ORDER BY customerAccountName asc

If I point the application back to the MySQL database, the application runs fine.

if I make a query in mysql of the columns status and etl_exec I only have 1 and 0

I think that 1= true and 0=false.

but in db2 don't works

I forget to say it, if I replace true by literal 1 I have the next problem:

```
NoMethodError in WelcomeController#index undefined method `customerAccountName' for #<CustomerAccount:0x007f5724544570> Did you mean? customeraccountname customeraccountname? customeraccountname= customeraccountname_was customeraccountname_change customeraccountuser customeraccountname_changed? customeraccountuser? customeraccountuser= customeraccountserver
```

here the specifications:

S.O (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)
db2 v10.5
ruby version 2.3.1
Rails version 4.1.6

and columns in db2:

Column name----Data type name

STATUS --------SMALLINT
ETL_EXEC------ SMALLINT

in Mysql

status----------tinyint(1)
etl_exec--------tinyint(1)

Comment: Please provide additional details, such as what version of RoR you have and the version / platform that your DB2 database is running.

Answer (score 1):

Present versions of Db2 LUW do not alias literals like TRUE/FALSE to 1/0.  Either use host-variables of the correct datatype (with values 1 or 0 as appropriate for numeric datatypes) or replace the TRUE literal value by 1 in the query.

If you still get the same exception, then edit your question to specify the Db2 column-datypes for each of the columns in the query

Comment: You should update your question, not paste follow-ups in comments @milloslex

Comment: excuse me @joe I'm new here

Comment: Your question is now the NoMethodError , and not the sqlcode -401 from Db2 which was your original question.  These may be unrelated symptoms. You may get answers from a separate new question specifically for the NoMethodError exception. though you may need to provide more details (such as Ruby code/configuration files).